# wsdl2java goal is not generating client classes

Tags: eclipse, maven, cxf

I tried below build in pom.xml file.

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                                <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/abc.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                </wsdlOptions>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

I am using eclipse. Tried right clicking the project->run as->maven generate sources but it is not generating client classes for me. Infact it is not even creating generated/cxf folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your plugins in a misplaced section within the pom: If you want them be applied to the containing project, they should be within project > build > plugins.

Comment: I removed <pluginManagement> tag from pom.xml and tried. Now it is generating client classes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use command line to run maven plug-ins. Run a terminal and just build your project with

```
mvn clean install
```

it should generate your clients classes.